# Software or web-app to draw diagrams that appear hand-drawn

Tags: graphs, charts, diagram

I'm looking for software / online app (web-app) that is able to draw some cool diagrams like these:

The first one is from JSNation presentation:
https://github.com/sokra/slides/blob/master/content/ModuleFederationWebpack5.md
[image]

The second one is from clickhouse documents:
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/kafka
[image]

If you think these diagrams are drawn by hand I would appreciate the device or tools or the knowledge that could help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome Hamed!  Do you have any OS preference (when not a web-app)?  Also, do you have any price range, or are you only looking for recommendations for gratis tools?  If you can update your question and tags, that will help us help you.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate No I'm just lokking for something that does the work as close possible :)

Comment: Sounds good! Thanks! I removed the web-app tag because you are not only looking for web-apps.  That's how our community currently handles tags (a tag indicates a requirement).  I'm glad to see Thomas was able to find you some good options!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another tool, that has a very close look and feel to what you've shown, is called Excalidraw (https://excalidraw.com/).

This is a web tool, that claims to only store it's data in your browser.

I do see it uses the same font as your examples, and the arrows of the 2nd example look exactly the same (in my subjective opinion).

Comment: This is so cool thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a single tool that would create all sorts of diagrams and look hand drawn. However, for some diagrams, I can recommend (because I use them myself):

- **Sequence diagrams**: [Web Sequence Diagrams](https://www.websequencediagrams.com/) set to style "napkin" or [JS Sequence Diagrams](https://bramp.github.io/js-sequence-diagrams/) with theme "hand drawn".
- **Class diagrams**: [yUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/draw) set to style "scruffy"
- **Wireframes**: [Balsamiq](https://balsamiq.com/wireframes/) has at least 2 styles that look hand drawn. Unfortunately, that one is commercial.

Comment: Hamed, if you will, let us know which one of Thomas' recommendations worked best for you and got the "look" most closely matching the images you posted.  Feel free to write an answer indicating that tool.  Thanks!

Comment: Typically I would write one answer per tool I recommend, so each tool can be voted for individually. In this case however, it was more like "you need all of these to do the task", so I put it into one answer. I hope for other answers, ideally for a single tool that allows multiple forms of diagrams.